# Smarty: extract data

Tags: php, smarty

I have a variable **{$ldata}** showing **['Date', 'Clicks', 'Downloads'],['2014-07-24', 5, 0]**

I want to extract from **['2014-07-24', 5, 0]** the last two digits (Clicks and Downloads) in different new variables.

I'm stuck at this part.. I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to be very well documented in Smarty's documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl something like `{$ldata[1][1]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
{assign var=foo value=", "|explode:$ldata} 
{$foo[0]}
{$foo[1]}
{$foo[2]|substr:0:-1}
```

Comment: Looks like it's working but appears this:

Clicks: 5 
Downloads: 0]

How I can remove the last character "]"

Comment: use {$foo[2]|substr:0:-1}

Comment: @AlfonsoMarketing if this did helped you kindly repay the effort made by the answer by accepting it.